# Is it possible to change AdWhirl banner colors programmatically?

Tags: ios, ios5, adwhirl

I know that ads colors can be set up in account settings, but I want to change colors to be the same as in view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdWhirl does not provide special functionality to set banner colors.  If you know how to directly set the colors for the networks you are mediating with programmatically, you can edit the source for those respective ad network adapters and specify those colors in that network's ad request.